# Call by reference

Tags: programming, variables, pointer

I am trying to learn 'call by reference'. I want to call a function `fcn1` from the main loop and pass a reference of the local variable `var` to the function `fcn1`. Next step is to call a second function `fcn2` from the function `fcn1` and pass again the reference of the local loop variable `var`. I always get this error massage:

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

Here a small example code:

```
void fcn1(int *variable)
{
  fcn2(&variable);
}

void fcn2(int *variable)
{
  //do something with the variable
}

void setup()
{

}

void loop()
{
  int var = 1000;
  fcn1(&var);
}
```

I tried to solve that issue by using:

```
void fcn1(int *variable)
{
  fcn2(*variable);
}
```

But it's the same error.

By deleting the `*` respectively `&` it works fine, but is it still a reference?

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I interpret your answer and the link correctly, the following code works only with references, right? void fcn1(int &variable) { variable++; fcn2(variable); } void fcn2(int &variable) { Serial.println(variable); } void setup() { Serial.begin(9600); } void loop() { static int var = 1000; fcn1(var); delay(1000); } Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, however, it will not compile that way .. int & variable denotes a pointer, to increase it, you should use variable++.

Answer (score 7):

```
void fcn1(int *variable)
{
  fcn2(*variable);
}
```

This function takes a pointer to an integer as parameter, and then passes the value of the integer to the second function.

To do it by reference, use an ampersand (`&`, not to be confused with the address-of operator).

```
void fcn1(int &variable) {
  // Do something to variable
}
```

For example:

```
void increment(int &variable) { // Reference to an integer
  variable++;
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  int a = 1;
  Serial.println(a); // 1
  increment(a);
  Serial.println(a); // 2
}
void loop() {}
```

---

You could achieve the same thing using pointers, but using references is much cleaner and easier to read.

```
void increment(int *variable) { // Pointer to an integer
  ++*variable; // dereference first, then increment value 
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  int a = 1;
  Serial.println(a); // 1
  increment(&a); // address of a
  Serial.println(a); // 2
}
void loop() {}
```

Please note: this question is not specific to Arduino, it is just C++. For questions like this, it is best to google for 'C++ pass by reference' instead of 'Arduino pass by reference'.